# TinyMCE: tags inside a-tag

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE 4.1.10 and have a problem with tags inside <a>-tags:

I need to insert code in the following markup inside the code viewer:

```
<a><h3>something</h3></a>
```

Generally I want every tag to be possible inside the <a>-tag (besides another <a>-tag).
But TinyMCE does a ridiculous cleanup:

```
<p><a></a></p>
<h3><a>something</a></h3>
<p></p>
```

I've already made following modifications in the setup:

```
extended_valid_elements : "a[*]",//allow empty <a>-tag
valid_children : "+a[div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text]",//allow some children in the <a>-tag
verify_html: false,
```

It doesn't make any sense at all what TinyMCE is doing here.
The [TinyMCE-website](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:schema) is telling me it uses html5-specification by default:

> The schema option enables you to switch between the HTML4 and HTML5
>   schema. This controls the valid elements and attributes that can be
>   placed in the HTML. This value can either be the default html5, html4
>   or html5-strict.

And in the [HTML5-Specifiations](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-a-element) you can read:

> The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

And now I don't get anything despite HTML5 valid markup AND extra `valid-children` setting in TinyMCE.